# How to skip the unique constraint validation on same document update

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have an update call as below in my NestJs project to update a mongoose model.

```html
    async updateRole(role_id: ObjectId, request: any): Promise<any> {
      return this.roleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(role_id, {...request});
    }
```

Here is the request I'm passing

```
{
    "name":"Super-Admin",
    "application": "62b2dbfd82045f40ea884334",
    "active":true,
    "privileges": ["62b2dbfd82045f40ea884334","62b2dbfd82045f40ea884334"],
    "updated_by": "Abhilash.Shajan1@gmail.com"
}
```

Below is my role schema

```html
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  application: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Application',
    autopopulate: true,
    required: true
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  privileges: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Privilege',
    autopopulate: true
  }],
  created_by: {
    type: String
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date
  },
  updated_by: {
    type: String
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date
  }
});

RoleSchema.index( { name: 1, application: 1 }, { unique: true } );

export { RoleSchema };
```

I already created a document (This is the only document now present in the roles collection) with the above request. Now I'm trying to update its `active` field to true.

Since i have unique compound index in the schema, it does not allow me to update the active field, I'm getting unique contraint error on both application and name field.

This error will be meaningful if i have another document with same name and application in the collection, but there is not.

Another way is to pass the active field alone in the request. But it will not help in my case because the UI is always passing the whole fields which include the unchanged values as well.

Any suggestions ?